# Undo a git push on github

Tags: git, github

I made a mistake .... and I don't know how to fix it.

I explain the issue.

I was working on my project, and I did a first commit. 
In this commit 2 big useless files had been added...
I didn't wanted these files so I did a

```
git rm file
```

Then commited again.
And I'm stupid, because I pushed to github hehehe :).

I think you've found out the problem...

How can I remove definitively these files from my local and github repositories (especially github...)

I found some help on the internet, but I don't want to break all my repository.

Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If no one else has pulled, you should just get your local branch back to how you want it (probably by either resetting to a previous position, or by doing an interactive rebase to remove the unwanted commit), then push again to github with the `-f` (force) option:

```
git push -f <remote-name> <branch-name>
```

If other people have pulled, the usual advice applies: read the [recovering from upstream rebase](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_recovering_from_upstream_rebase) section of the git-rebase man page to see what you're doing to the others before you do your forced update.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted remove (not revert, remove) last commit with new files, I think you should do:

```
git reset --soft "HEAD^"
```

Anyway since you already pushed it to github, you can't remove it without re-creating git repo. This is how it work, you can revert each commit, for example commit where you deleted those 2 big files. Since it's new repo and you are talking about initial commit, re-creating repo looks for me as best idea.

Comment: "you can't remove it without re-creating git repo" er, yes you can. It may upset other people if they've pulled, but you can do it.

Comment: I had no idea that you can remove it from remote repo, thanks mate.

Comment: Just `git reset HEAD^` is OK; the mixed reset also resets the staging area but (as opposed to `--hard`) leaves the working directory intact. From there, `git add -p` is often the next step.