# How to cancel a push to GitHub after it has been done

Tags: git, github, push

this might be an easy question for somebody experienced in Git, but when I google the words, I always get pages about problems *with* the pushing to GitHub. I have the exact opposite issue: I pushed something I should've never pushed.

I forked on GitHub a public repository of an open source project, created a local clone of it, worked on it, and commited and pushed my changes to my forked repository on GitHub.

Somehow, the diff on GitHub completely screwed up and got me 700 added rows and 700 deleted rows (probably because of indentation), so I would like to cancel the push I did, do the changes again being careful of indentation, and commit&push it again *to the original version of my forked repository when it was cloned*.

I won't bother you with the tens of trials I did, and the various results I managed to obtain. The question is: if you had this problem, how would you solve it?

Thanks
Duccio

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undo a git push on github](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692938/undo-a-git-push-on-github)

Answer (score 3):

Just do `git push --force origin` from a correct state of your local repository.

Answer (score 3):

If you'll get your local repository in the correct state (perhaps an interactive rebase to remove the offending commit?), you should be able to force push to GitHub:

`git push -f origin <branchname>`

Answer (score 3):

I can't give you the exact line without you listing the commits.  But you use a force push to change back.

`git push -f origin oldcomitSHA1:branchname`

Oh and BTW all the stuff you did after can make things worse.  Don't ask me how I know.